Temperature dependence of tunnel current
The temperature dependence of the conductance of a diode can be found by Shockley's diode equation which is:$I_{d} = I_{s}e^{-\frac{V_{d}}{kV_{t}}}$ .By differentiating over $dV_{d}$ we get $\frac{dI_{d}}{dV_{d}}(g_{m})=-\frac{I_{s}}{kV_{t}}e^{-\frac{V_{d}}{kV_{t}}}$
$g_{m}\rightarrow g_{m}(T)$ because $V_{t}\rightarrow V_{t}(T)$.
And it can easily proven since $V_{t}$ is proportional to $T$ then $g_{m}(T)$ is inversely proportional to $T$.
The temperature dependence of the conductance of a tunnel diode (at least when we are close to the negative differential region of the tunnel diode)
can be found in a similar way by taking the equation for the tunnel current:$I_{d} = I_{p}\frac{V_{d}}{V_{p}}e^{1-\frac{V_{d}}{V_{p}}}$. By differentiating over $dV_{d}$ we get:
$\frac{dI_{d}}{dV_{d}}(g_{m})=I_{p}\frac{V_{p}e^{1-\frac{Vd}{Vp}}-V_{d}e^{\frac{V_{p}-V_d}{V_p}}}{V_{p}^{2}}$.
On a first glance the tunnel current doesnt have a temperature dependency but I dont think this makes sense.So I asking if anyone knows the temperature dependency of the $V_p \rightarrow V_p(T)$ ,which is the voltage of the tunnel diode when the maximum tunnel current passes through the tunnel diode and $I_p \rightarrow I_p(T)$ which is the maximum tunnel current.
